# Analogous of Markov's inequality for the lower bound

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality, probability-distributions, random

Consider a positive random variable $X$ and call $E[X]$ its expectation.
For any positive $a \in \mathbb{R}$, an upper bound for the probability of $P(X>a)$ is provided by the Markov's Inequality,
$$
P(X>a) \leq \frac{E[X]}{a},
$$
Is there an analogous lower bound that is based only on the knowledge of the expectation?

Comment: After a Google http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paley%E2%80%93Zygmund_inequality

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider a distribution with 
$$P(X=m\delta)=1-\delta$$
$$P\left(X=m\tfrac{1-\delta+\delta^2}{\delta}\right)=\delta$$
then $E[X]=m$ but $P(X\gt a )$ can be made arbitrarily small by choosing $\delta \lt \frac{a}{m}$ and if necessarily smaller.

So to get something useful, you would need some constraint on $X$ such as a given maximum or a given variance.